# Why does Flutter not recognize my abstract class in Visual Code?

Tags: flutter, class, dart, import

I have an abstract class called `IIdentified` which I use like an interface for generic widgets and methods. My problem is that Flutter does not recognize the class `IIdentified` when I import it. Intellisense doesn't give me suggestions to import the class either.

The widget that needs to use `IIdentified` but doesn't recognize it as a class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:..._..._mobile/themeConfig.dart' as themeConfig;

class LoaderDropdownButton<IIdentified> extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool enableSelect;
  final String text;
  final List<IIdentified> data;
  final void Function(IIdentified) onChange;

  LoaderDropdownButton(
      {@required this.enableSelect,
      @required this.text,
      @required this.data,
      @required this.onChange});

  @override
  LoaderDropdownButtonState createState() => LoaderDropdownButtonState();
}

class LoaderDropdownButtonState<IIdentified> extends State<LoaderDropdownButton> {
  double displayWidth;
  double displayHeight;

  @override
  void initState() {
    init();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setDisplayDimensions();
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
      color: widget.enableSelect ? themeConfig.dropButtonBg : themeConfig.dropButtonDisabledBg,
      child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(canvasColor: Color(0xFFC5C5C5)),
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: new DropdownButton<IIdentified>(
              hint: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                      child: Text(
                        widget.text,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: widget.enableSelect
                              ? themeConfig.dropButtonFg
                              : themeConfig.dropButtonDisabledFg,
                          fontSize: displayWidth * 0.045,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                        color: widget.enableSelect
                            ? themeConfig.dropButtonFg
                            : themeConfig.dropButtonDisabledFg,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              iconSize: 0,
              isExpanded: true,
              items: buildItems(),
              onChanged: widget.onChange),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void init() {
    displayWidth = 1;
    displayHeight = 1;
  }

  setDisplayDimensions() {
    if (displayWidth == 1) displayWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    if (displayHeight == 1) displayHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<IIdentified>> buildItems() {
    return widget.data.map((IIdentified dataItem) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<IIdentified>(
        value: dataItem,
        child: Text("s"),
      );
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

`IIdentified` class:

```
abstract class IIdentified {
  String id;
  String name;
}
```

Warning when I hover over the imported `IIdentified` class, does not understand it's being used by the widget:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this because you are importing your class `as themeConfig`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how I referred to the class within the <> for the widget. Do it like this instead:

```
class LoaderDropdownButton<T extends IIdentified> extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool enableSelect;
  final String text;
  final List<T> data;
  final void Function(T) onChange;
  final bool isLoading;

  LoaderDropdownButton(
      {@required this.enableSelect,
      @required this.text,
      @required this.data,
      @required this.onChange,
      @required this.isLoading});

  @override
  LoaderDropdownButtonState createState() => LoaderDropdownButtonState();
}
```